# How to make Splash in Single Activity Architecture?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-splashscreen

I need to create a splash screen in an application configured with Single Activity Architecture.

It would be common to create a drawable file and set it as a theme, or to use the "splash screen API" provided by Google.
But in my situation, I can't use those because I have to show any text or image(like ads) on splash which is not the app logo, or handle the event.

It seems that the easiest way is to create Splash Activity separately, which is against SAA.
Therefore, my idea is to start with MainActivity, but to create SplashFragment, show the first screen as SplashFragment, and move to MainFragment when the conditions are met (ex: After a certain period of time, the load of data to be shown in Main Fragment is completed).

What worries me is that I saw in some article that organizing Splash as Activity or Fragment is an anti pattern, but I don't know if the way I thought would be okay. Would it be better to approach it with the feeling of StartFragment, not Splash?

Comment: The *only* thing you should be implementing a splash screen with is the [Splash Screen APIs](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen).

Comment: @ianhanniballake Recommend you add that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

To implement a launch page using a Fragment instead of an Activity, you can follow the idea of a single Activity architecture. You can display the launch Fragment in the Activity first, and then replace it with the main Fragment when the toggle condition is met. If you need a highly customized launch page, you can also consider using it With custom views instead of fragments, you can also consider using a Adapter-Based architecture for complex applications, which allows for more flexibility in reusing components.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have splash screen in single Activity Architecture to acheived this you need to use Android Navigation Architecture Component.
If you are fimilier with android navigation component then just add some lines in navation graph in action like this below

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/registration_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/splash">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/splash"
        android:name="com.example.application.fragments.SplashFragment"
        android:label="@string/spash"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash">


<action
        android:id="@+id/splashToLoginAction"
        app:destination="@+id/loginFrag"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/left_to_right"
        app:launchSingleTop="true"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/right_to_left"
        app:popUpTo="@id/splash"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

</navigation>
```

Otherwise first you need to learn Android Naviation Component in Android for this check the detail information from below link

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/get-started

if you need more information regarding android navigation contact me here.

---